# How to refresh just a specific portion of an HTML page?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, refresh, reload

I have one HTML file containing several `<div>` elements. I want to refresh just part of the page using either JavaScript or C#.  Can someone help?

I am trying to do it this way:

```
document.location.reload(document.getElementById("contentdiv"));
```

It reloads the whole page.  I wish to reload `contentdiv`.   If `contentdiv` is at the middle of the page then it should load only that part.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could move the contents of everything you want reloaded into an external file, and either use the `<iframe>` tag and only refresh that frame, or you could use JavaScript and refresh the div with Ajax.

Ajax isn't that simple to explain in a short answer, but you can find plenty of information on it here: http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_example.asp or if you use a framework like jQuery ajax is much easier.

iFrames can be implemented (on mypage.html, for example) like so: `<iframe src='mypagecontent.html'></iframe>` and in mypagecontent.html you could use `<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.reload();</script>` to refresh the frame.

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but hope it helps somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

What ASP.NET Framework are you using?  If you are using Web Forms, look into [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx)